# A matrix problem :)

Tags: matrices

> If $l_i,m_i,n_i$  ; $i=1,2,3$ denote the direction cosines of three mutually perpendicular vectors in space, provided that $AA^T=I$ ,where
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
>         l_1 & m_1 & n_1 \\
>         l_2 & m_2 & n_2 \\
>         l_3 & m_3 & n_3 \\
>         \end{bmatrix} $$

I couldn't quite understand the question. Sorry for not posting 'how I tried to solve the answer'.

Please provide assistance.
Thank you. :)

Comment: Provided should be "prove" should not?

Comment: it is not to prove but to denote the direction cosines. is it not?

Comment: Please make the title more informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider first $$A^TA=  \begin{bmatrix}l_1 & l_2 & l_3 \\m_1 & m_2 & m_3 \\n_1 & n_2 & n_3 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}l_1 & m_1 & n_1 \\l_2 & m_2 & n_2 \\l_3 & m_3 & n_3 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \cdots $$ by working out a few of the elements in terms of the components of $\mathbf {l,m,n}$. Then ask yourself: if $AB=I$, then what is $A^{-1}$? Therefore, what is $BA$?

Comment: what is meant by 'direction cosines of three mutually perpendicular vectors in space'?

Comment: Oh, it means $\mathbf{l\cdot m}=0$ etc. (mutually perpendicular) and $\lVert \mathbf l\rVert^2=1$ etc. (unit length, direction cosines = projections onto axes only).

Comment: can u elaborate further? I still couldnt understand...  +1

Comment: It just means they are three, unit length, orthogonal vectors. That's all.